# Cannot fix this hole

Tags: faces

I have holes in some faces and not on all does the F work.
Can any one help me?
[image]

EDIT:
I tried to delete the face like lemon said with X and "only face" and then this is the result:
[image]

[image]

Comment: That can be overlapping faces. Two faces on each other and inverted normals for each. Try to remove one "X" then 'only face'

Comment: I edit my question with a picture of what happens then...

Comment: Filling it later with F did work though. I will try that with the rest too

Comment: OK, so come back to vertex selection mode (ctrl+tab then vertex) and delete the vertex in the center. Now you should have a "real hole" and would be able to create a face with F.

Comment: There is no vertex in the center. With 2 it worked but i am at one now where i delete the face and then fill it and it will still show the hole

Comment: You should edit your question and upload your file (or part of it) using this link http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's added now.

Comment: yes. This is due to the solidify modifier. The faces it is adding are odd due to some ngons in your model. Is it really needed here? What I advice it to remove it, check the model and (eventually) add it afterwards

Comment: Hi, I checked your .blend file and I agree with lemon, if you remove the solidify modifier the problem disappears. Also make sure you don't have N-gons, I found that one of them is actually one of the weird-looking faces while I was checking your model.

Comment: Rapidly remodeled if that can help [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4813" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4813/)